# Update second column

Tags: oracle

I have a table "TEST_TABLE" with two columns TABLE_NAME and RECORD_COUNT.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VcEIn.png)

We want to update the column RECORD_COUNT by taking the total records in table specified in TABLE_NAME.

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with dynamic SQL but why be complicated?
Create a view

```
Create view my_tables as
Select 
  'table_1' as "table name",
  count(*)  as "rows"
From table_1
```

Add the following for each table

```
  Union all
Select 'table_2',count(*) From table_2
```

You can then use the view like a table:

```
Select * from my_tables;
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, but - why wouldn't you use information Oracle already provides for you? You should regularly gather statistics anyway, so:

```
SQL> execute dbms_stats.gather_schema_stats(ownname => 'SCOTT', estimate_percent  => null);

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

and then fetch `num_rows` from `user_tables`:

```
SQL> select table_name, num_rows from user_tables where rownum <= 10;

TABLE_NAME             NUM_ROWS
-------------------- ----------
EMP                          14
DEPT                          4
BONUS                         0
SALGRADE                      5
DUMMY                         1
TBL_ERROR                     1
AUDIT_TAB                     2
SOURCE_DET                    3
EXAMPLE                       1
FLIGHT                        0

10 rows selected.

SQL>
```

It can't be much worse than your attempt (due to possible frequent changes to tables' contents; inserts and deletes) because you'd collect your own data periodically (how often?) anyway.

---

If it *has to be* your way, then you'd use dynamic SQL, looping through all tables in your schema and actually *count* number of rows:

```
SQL> create table test_table
  2    (table_name varchar2(30),
  3     num_rows   number);

Table created.

SQL> create or replace procedure p_test as
  2    l_cnt number;
  3  begin
  4    execute immediate 'truncate table test_table';
  5    for cur_R in (select table_name from user_tables) loop
  6      execute immediate 'select count(*) from ' ||cur_R.table_name into l_Cnt;
  7      insert into test_table (table_name, num_rows) values (cur_r.table_name, l_cnt);
  8    end loop;
  9  end;
 10  /

Procedure created.
```

Running the procedure and viewing the result:

```
SQL> exec p_test;

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * From test_Table where rownum <= 10;

TABLE_NAME             NUM_ROWS
-------------------- ----------
EMP                          14
DEPT                          4
BONUS                         0
SALGRADE                      5
DUMMY                         1
TBL_ERROR                     1
AUDIT_TAB                     2
SOURCE_DET                    3
EXAMPLE                       1
FLIGHT                        0

10 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Note that performance will suffer as number of tables and number of rows stored in them grows.

---

If I were you, I'd go for the first option.